# How do we fit a sigmoid function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

For reproducibility reasons, I am sharing the simple dataset I am working [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ip-ez4X4FGI07lWr6gmyz3PzIaUDbhR-).

To make it clear of what I am doing - from column 2, I am reading the current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is greater, I keep comparing. If the current value is smaller than the previous row's value, I want to divide the current value (smaller) by the previous value (larger). Accordingly, below is my source code.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import beta

protocols = {}

types = {"data_v": "data_v.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }
    plt.figure(); plt.clf()
    plt.plot(quotient_times, quotient, ".", label=protname, color="blue")
    plt.ylim(0, 1.0001)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("quotient_times")
    plt.ylabel("quotient")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    sns.distplot(quotient, hist=False, label=protname)
```

This gives the following plots.

[image]

[image]

As we can see from the plots

- **Data-V** has a quotient of 0.8 when the `quotient_times` is less than 3 and the quotient remains 0.5 if the `quotient_times` is
  greater than 3.

I have also fitted it into a beta distribution using the following code

```
xt = plt.xticks()[0]  
xmin, xmax = min(xt), max(xt)  
lnspc = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, len(quotient))

alpha,beta,loc,scale = stats.beta.fit(quotient)  
pdf_beta = stats.beta.pdf(lnspc, alpha, beta,loc, scale)  
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_beta, label="Data-V", color="darkblue", alpha=0.9)
plt.xlabel('$quotient$')
#plt.ylabel(r'$p(x|\alpha,\beta)$')
plt.title('Beta Distribution')
plt.legend(loc="best", frameon=False)
```

[image]

How can we fit the `quotient` (defined above) into a sigmoid function to have a plot something like the following?

[image]

Comment: I recommend you the lmfit package. There you have an easy way to implement your own fit-functions. (Hope I understood your problem correctly)

Comment: `lmfit` for sigmoid function? I haven't worked with it before but can you try with the dataset I shared, Richard? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't fitting a dataset into sigmoid the same as using a sigmoid classifier? You just need to extract the parameters. Scikit learn has sigmoid classifier that's very easy to use.

Comment: I have done something very similar in R, would it help if I share that?

Comment: @MedImage, thank you but I want it in Python. If you could share you answer your answer in Python with the same data I shared, it would be cool and I will mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: First of all I think you have to fit the cumulative sum to the sigmoid...

Comment: @anki, I did that but I get a straight line. Could you try and share your answer?

Comment: @Brown, your minimal example is not working, what is ```beta_value```? And if you try to fit ```quotient``` (which is your first plot?!) then you will most likely get a straight line.

Comment: @anki, Sorry it was a typo. I have edited now. Exactly, I am getting a straight line. That's why I am looking for a way to make it look like a sigmoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to fit a `sigmoid`, or actually a [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). This can be varied in several ways, such as slope, midpoint, magnitude and offset.

Here's the code that defines that `sigmoid` function and utilizes the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` function to minimize the error by tuning the parameters.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def sigmoid (x, A, h, slope, C):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp ((x - h) / slope)) *  A + C

# Fits the function sigmoid with the x and y data
#   Note, we are using the cumulative sum of your beta distribution!
p, _ = curve_fit(sigmoid, lnspc, pdf_beta.cumsum())

# Plots the data
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_beta.cumsum(), label='original')
plt.plot(lnspc, sigmoid(lnspc, *p), label='sigmoid fit')
plt.legend()

# Show parameters for the fit
print(p)
```

This gives you the following plot:

[image: comparison original data and sigmoid fit]

and the following parameter space (for the above used function):

```
[-1.82910694e+01  4.88870236e-01  6.15103201e-03  1.82895890e+01]
```

If you want to fit the variables `quotient_time` and `quotient`, you simply change the variables.

```
...
p, _ = curve_fit(sigmoid, quotient_times, quotient)
...
```

and plot it:

[image: quotient and sigmoid fit]

Comment: I am still not sure if this is what you actually "want" (scientifically), but this is what you have asked for ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I have asked but could you try it with the dataset I shared?

Comment: @Brown, this is your dataset! This is the beta distribution cumulative sum.

Comment: Really? Where are you passing the beta fit of the data then? May I need coffee :-D

Comment: @Brown, it is the ```pdf_beta.cumsum()``` command, ```pdf_beta``` is what you provided in your example code. I additionally provided now the fit of the ```quotient``` and the ```quotient_times``` (as your first plot). Hope it helps. And when the data is so heterogenously distributed, then the fit will be most likely not too good.

Comment: It does help and thank you so much. ACCEPTED your answer!

Comment: Hi Anki, if it is not too much to ask. Here is how I want it. The sigmoid should be the weight of the two peaks (as you see from the second plot i included with my question). `Disrtibution(quotient, quotient_times)=w1*Distr_peak(0.5)+(1-w1)Distr_peak(0.8)` where w1 is a sigmoid function that depends on `quotient_times`. Distr_peak(0.5) is a beta distribution centered around 0.5. Why sigmoid because w1=0.5 around `quotient_times`=3. Disrtibution(quotient, quotient_times=3)=0.5 *Distr_peak(0,8)+0.5*Distrpeak(0.5)